# Laravel 5 On POST Status 302 Found

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to create new post useing laravel , ajax and s3 , But every time i try submit the form i get Status Code:302 Found , I Hope really some help me

**Firebug**

[Here in firebug result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qeHc.png)

**META**

```
<meta name="csrf" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

**VIEW**

The form view with csrf token

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                {!! Form::open(array(
                    'class' => 'form',
                    'novalidate' => 'novalidate',
                    'files' => true
                )) !!}

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('title', 'Title: ') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cats">Select Category list :</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
                        <option value="">Select Category</option>
                        @foreach($category as $cat)
                            <option value="{{$cat->id}}">{{$cat->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cats">Select Subcategory list :</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="subcategory" name="subcategory">
                        <option value=>Select Subcategory</option>
                            <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('image', 'Upload Image') !!}
                    {!! Form::file('image', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('description', 'Description: ') !!}
                    {!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('email', 'Your Email: ') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::submit('Post Free Ad', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
                </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

First valid the requist and than create new email for the user if he did't have and than save the post with the user

```
public function storePostAds(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
           'title' => 'required',
           'description' => 'required',
           'image' => 'required',
           'category_id' => 'required',
           'subcategory_id' => 'required',
        ]);
        $email = $request['email'];
        $title = $request['title'];
        $description = $request['description'];
        $category = $request['category_id'];
        $subcategory = $request['subcategory_id'];
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $user = User::where('email', $email)->first();
        if(!$user){
            $user = new User();
            $user->email = $email;
            $user->save();
        }
        if($image->isValid()){
            $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $key = 'images/'.$name;
            Storage::disk('s3')->put($key, file_get_contents($image));
        }
        $post = new Post();
        $post->title = $title;
        $post->description = $description;
        $post->category_id = $category;
        $post->subcategory_id = $subcategory;
        $post->image = $image;
        $user->posts()->save($post);
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

**Ajax**

ajax to get subcategory foreach category after select

```
(function($){
    $('#category').on('change', function(e){

        var cat_id = e.target.value;
        $.get('/ajax-subcategory?cat_id=' + cat_id, function(data){
            var subcategory = $('#subcategory');
            subcategory.empty();
            $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj){
               subcategory.append('<option value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+subcatObj.name+'</option>');
            });
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: uuuh, much code. Can you post to the url using postman? And: what does the log say, anything more specific than 500?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your category and subcategory fields are "category" and "subcategory" but are being referred to as "category_id" and "subcategory_id" respectively in your Controller code.

Comment: To Rahul Govind: I think your answer almost right after change the category and subcategory fields in the Controller , it's look's like everything ok the data saved with new user,  redirect to home page but no image name and still give me the 302 Found !!!

Comment: How about after changing file_get_contents($image) to file_get_contents($image->getRealPath()) ? And 302 is the HTTP Status code for redirects.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else had my issue, when first creating your fields on the model, your fields may be required. if the controller is not built correctly, instead of errors it returns 302 on the post response. Try checking you enter data for all the form fields before submitting the form.